# C# Enable/Disable multiple textbox based on combobox selection

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox, enable-if, consolidation

I am just an ordinary guy who is learning how to code. I don't like when code looks sloppy and can be consolidated. With that being said I need to consolidate some code, but I have failed to find information on how to do it.

I am trying to enable/disable multiple textbox based of combobox selection.

Here is the long and ugly code I am trying to consolidate

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Combobox_Process_Selected_Index = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 0)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 1)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 2)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 3)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 4)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 5)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = true;
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 6)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = true;
            textBox7.Enabled = true;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 7)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = true;
            textBox7.Enabled = true;
            textBox8.Enabled = true;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 8)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = true;
            textBox7.Enabled = true;
            textBox8.Enabled = true;
            textBox9.Enabled = true;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 9)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = true;
            textBox7.Enabled = true;
            textBox8.Enabled = true;
            textBox9.Enabled = true;
            textBox10.Enabled = true;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 10)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = true;
            textBox7.Enabled = true;
            textBox8.Enabled = true;
            textBox9.Enabled = true;
            textBox10.Enabled = true;
            textBox11.Enabled = true;
            textBox12.Enabled = false;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 11)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = true;
            textBox7.Enabled = true;
            textBox8.Enabled = true;
            textBox9.Enabled = true;
            textBox10.Enabled = true;
            textBox11.Enabled = true;
            textBox12.Enabled = true;
            textBox13.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (Combobox_Process_Selected_Index == 12)
        {
            textBox2.Enabled = true;
            textBox3.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = true;
            textBox5.Enabled = true;
            textBox6.Enabled = true;
            textBox7.Enabled = true;
            textBox8.Enabled = true;
            textBox9.Enabled = true;
            textBox10.Enabled = true;
            textBox11.Enabled = true;
            textBox12.Enabled = true;
            textBox13.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just have to say thank you very much [h8red](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2559094/h8red). I went from a massive amount of junk code to less than 10 lines of code.

Here is the resulting consolidation of code by placing the textboxes in a panel and then enabling/disabling them based on the combo box user input.

```
        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set a counter to track textbox number and compare with combobox selection
        int countTB = 0;

        //grab combobox selection and place as an integer
        int Combobox_Process_Selected_Index = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;

        //this looks at each child control in my panel (named panel1)
        foreach (Control child in panel1.Controls)  
        {
            //this looks at each textbox individually and enables them until combo selection is reached and disables the rest
            TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;              
            if (countTB < Combobox_Process_Selected_Index)
            {
                textBox.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
                textBox.Enabled = false;
            countTB++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Formal acceptance of my answer would be appreciated then.

Answer (score 0):

You need a container control class to have all the textboxes in it. The simplest one is [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Just add all the texboxes to `panel.Controls` and you will be able to access them in a loop. You will also have to manually set a tab in order to be able to enable only some of them.